# How to compare two Dictionary<string,int> to find if any of the value has changed?

Tags: c#

I have two dictionary `personalizePatientChartDictionary` and `personalizePatientChartDictionaryOriginal`. Both have same key but value can be different. I want to find out if there is any difference in value for a key. I have come up with the following function. Is there any better way of doing this? I am using .NET 4.0.

```
void CompareOriginalValues()
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> Origkvp in personalizePatientChartDictionaryOriginal)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in personalizePatientChartDictionary)
        {
            if ((Origkvp.Key == kvp.Key) && (Origkvp.Value != kvp.Value))
            {
                hasDictionaryChanged = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (hasDictionaryChanged)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (var kvp in personalizePatientChartDictionaryOriginal)
{
    int value;
    if (personalizePatientChartDictionary.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value))
    {
        if (kvp.Value != value)
        {
            hasDictionaryChanged = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this code (and your original code) don't detect if there are keys in one dictionary that aren't present in the other. It only checks that the value associated with a particular key in the first dictionary is associated with the same key in the second dictionary, but only if that key actually exists in the second dictionary.

Comment: Question states that both dictionaries contain same keys so you don't need to check if key actually exist in the second dictionary

Comment: @Andriy: Good point. It might well be better to make that assumption (and then throw an exception *if* there happened to be a missing key), but the OP's original code doesn't do that, and I've tried to keep the original logic, just improving its performance.

Answer (score 3):

Seems good. But it would be good to return **hasDictionaryChanged** to indicate that it changed

Comment: hasDictionaryChanged  is a page level property.This is the reason why it has not been returned.

Comment: Oh... then you should put the if statement right after the hasDictionaryChanged = true;

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using LINQ (don't forget to add "using System.Linq" to your usings)

```
bool hasDictionaryChanged = personalizePatientChartDictionaryOriginal.Except(personalizePatientChartDictionary).Count() > 0;
```

For more information about what you can do with LINQ, see [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx).

Comment: This will evaluate as true if there are keys in the first dictionary that aren't present in the second. This is different logic to that in the question, which only detects differences in values for keys that exist *in both dictionaries*. (Whether that logic is what the OP actually intended is another matter!)

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to write your own version of the dictionary class, inherit from dictionary and IComparable.

Then you could do `dictionary1.Compare(dictionary2);`

Here is a good resource for the ICompareable interface
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

Comment: This would then also work with complex objects stored in your dictionary, if that is what you require.

Comment: [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727) is NOT a good resource about .NET because it's about .NET 1.x. [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) is